# MonoTypeOperatorFunction is not assignable to parameter of type OperatorFunction

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

having a firebase service for getting students from firebase looking like this:

```
import {inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {Student} from '../../student-card/student-card.component';
import {collection, collectionData, Firestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {shareReplay} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentsService {

  private students$: Observable<Student[]> = from([]);

  private firestore = inject(Firestore);

  public getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    if (!this.students$) {
      const studentsCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'students');
      this.students$ = collectionData(studentsCollection, {idField: 'id'}).pipe(shareReplay(1)) as Observable<Student[]>;
    }

    return this.students$;
  }
}
```

and as soon as i add `shareReplay(1)` to the pipe it prompts me with the following error:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Student[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<(DocumentData | (DocumentData & { id: string; }))[], Student[]>'.   Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.     Type 'Observable<(DocumentData | (DocumentData & { id: string; }))[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Student[]>'.       Type '(DocumentData | (DocumentData & { id: string; }))[]' is not assignable to type 'Student[]'.         Type 'DocumentData | (DocumentData & { id: string; })' is not assignable to type 'Student'.           Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type 'Student': id, firstname, lastname, gender, clazzes`